# Suppress appearance of headline tags in pdf export

Tags: pdf, emacs, org-mode

I have headlines like

```
* Title                     :tag:
```

in my org file.  The `:tag:` text appears in the pdf export of the org file.  I don't want to see the tag-names when I export.  How do I configure the export so that the tags are not in the resulting pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an export [option to exclude tags](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings).

For example, add the following in-buffer setting:

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
```

Or customize the variable `org-export-with-tags`.